# Sum yearfrac between two columns in Excel over all rows

Tags: excel, function

I looked through the related questions, but none seemed to match this setup. Given a personnel table with begin and end dates, I would like to sum by year to allocation of each person. Table example:

```
           | begin    | end        | 2021 | 2022 | 2023
-----------+----------+------------+------+------+------
PersonA    | 1/1/2021 | 12/31/2022 |      |      |
PersonB    | 7/1/2021 |  6/30/2023 |      |      |
-----------+----------+------------+------+------+------
allocation |          |            | a_21 | a_22 | a_23
```

a_21 should amount to 1.0 + 0.5 = 1.5, a_22 to 2.0, a_23 to 0.5.

The trivial option would be calculating `YEARFRAC` per year in each cell, but in my spreadsheet I have other types of values in the cell. Is there a way to calculate the sums a_21, a_22, a_23 without creating the intermediate values?

I've tried a `SUM(YEARFRAC(MAX(B,DATE(D1,1,1)),MIN(C,DATE(D1,12,31))))`, but `YEARFRAC` is evaluated on the ranges `B` and `C` but not *individually* by row first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - unfortunately Min and Max don't work as you would wish them to in array formulas and tedious though it is, you have to use if statements instead:

```
=SUM(YEARFRAC(IF($B2:$B3>DATE(D1,1,1),$B2:$B3,DATE(D1,1,1)),IF($C2:$C3<DATE(D1,12,31),$C2:$C3,DATE(D1,12,31))))
```

[image]